# String interpolation with hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

My aim is to replace keys in a string with values in hash. I am doing it like this:

```
"hello %{name}, today is %{day}" % {name: "Tim", day: "Monday"}
```

If a key in the string in missing in the hash:

```
"hello %{name}, today is %{day}" % {name: "Tim", city: "Lahore"}
```

then it will throw an error.

```
KeyError: key{day} not found
```

Expected result should be:

```
"hello Tim, today is %{day}" or "hello Tim, today is "
```

Can someone guide me in a direction to replace only the matching keys without throwing any errors?

Comment: What's your expected result in the second case, i.e. if a key is missing?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Expected response can be "hello Tim, today is %{day}" or "hello Tim, today is ". I think second one will be preferred

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting with Ruby 2.3, `%` honors default values set via [`default=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D):

```
hash = {name: 'Tim', city: 'Lahore'}
hash.default = ''

'hello %{name}, today is %{day}' % hash
#=> "hello Tim, today is "
```

or dynamic defaults set via [`default_proc=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D):

```
hash = {name: 'Tim', city: 'Lahore'}
hash.default_proc = proc { |h, k| "%{#{k}}" }

'hello %{name}, today is %{day}' % hash
#=> "hello Tim, today is %{day}"
```

Note that only the missing key i.e. `:day` is passed to the proc. It is therefore unaware of whether you use `%{day}` or `%<day>s` in your format string which might result in a different output:

```
'hello %{name}, today is %<day>s' % hash
#=> "hello Tim, today is %{day}"
```

Comment: @Tachyons that's right, I've added the requirement to my answer.

Comment: I am using ruby 2.1.3 and this is not working. Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: @Abhishek you could use `gsub` to replace `%{...}` with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 3):

you can set a default hash value :

```
h = {name: "Tim", city: "Lahore"}
h.default = "No key"
p "hello %{name}, today is %{day}" % h #=>"hello Tim, today is No key"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the hash keys with spaces and it worked after converting the keys to symbols.

Hash with String keys (It returned an error on interpolation):

```
hash = {"First Name" => "Allama", "Last Name" => "Iqbal"}
```

Converting the hash keys to Symbols worked for me:

```
hash = {:"First Name" => "Allama", :"Last Name" => "Iqbal"}
hash.default = ''

'The %{First Name} %{Last Name} was a great poet.' % hash

// The Allama Iqbal was a great poet.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ended up making a utility for my needs.
Here is my Gist https://gist.github.com/Genkilabs/71b479e1b1300a581a85e047db1cbb43

```
  #@param String with %{key} interpolation fields
  #@param Hash or Rails Model
  #@returns String original with any keys replaced if they are in the hash, others ignored
  def self.interpolate str, obj
    #For the hash, we need to re-key the hash to be sure, and add default to skip missing interpolations
    safe_hash = (defined?(obj.attributes) ? obj.attributes : obj.to_h).symbolize_keys
    safe_hash.default_proc = proc{|h, k| "%{#{k}}" }
    #On the string side, safeguard any place ther is a symbol inside an interpolated field
    str.gsub('%{:', '%{') % safe_hash
  end
```